I am trying to show that $K: H_0^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a compact operator.
$\textbf{Suppose.}$

$\Omega$: bounded open in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
${W^{1,2}}(\Omega)$: the space of $u:\Omega \to\mathbb{R}$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ with a weak derivative $Du$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, and
${H_0}^1(\Omega)$ is the closure of ${C_0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in the Sobolev ${W^{1,2}}(\Omega)$ norm.
$L$ is a elliptic operator (divergence-form)
$Lu=f$ if and only if $B[u,v]= \langle f,v \rangle $ for all $v\in {H_0}^1(\Omega)$
where B is the bilinear form for $L$ and $\langle , \rangle$ is the $L^2$ inner product
$L_\gamma u:=Lu~+~\gamma u$ so that it has a unique solution $u$ in ${H_0}^1(\Omega)$ for each $f\in {H_0}^1(\Omega)$
$L_\gamma u=f$ if and only if $B_\gamma [u,v]= B[u,v]~+~\gamma\langle u,v \rangle =\langle f,v \rangle$ for all $v\in {H_0}^1(\Omega)$
where $B_\gamma$ is the bilinear form for $L_\gamma$

$\textbf{Problem.}$
Let $K: H_0^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that for all $f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, $Kf$ is a solution for $L_{\gamma} u = \gamma f $. Prove that $K$ is compact operator.
$\textbf{Proof.}$

We have some inequality

$f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$
$
 \Rightarrow \beta \| u \|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}^2 = B_\gamma [u, u] = \gamma  \langle f, u \rangle \leq \gamma \| f \|_{L_2(\Omega)} \| u \|_{L_2(\Omega)}\leq \gamma \| f \|_{L_2(\Omega)}\| u \|_{H_0^1(\Omega)} 
$
$
 \quad \text{where} \ u := Kf \in H_0^1(\Omega)
$
$
\Rightarrow \| Kf \|_{H_0^1(\Omega)} \leq N \| f \|_{L_2(\Omega)} \quad \cdots (1)
$
$
(\beta, d \ \text{does not depend on} \ f, \ \text{so does} \ N)
$

Compactness

$
\{ f_k \} : \text{bounded in} \ H_0^1(\Omega)
$
$
 \Rightarrow \{ f_k \} : \text{bounded in} \ L_2(\Omega)
$
$
\Rightarrow \{ K f_k \} : \text{bounded in} \ H_0^1(\Omega) ~~~~~~~~\because (1)
$
$
\Rightarrow \{ K f_k \} \ \text{has a convergent sequence} \ \{ K f_{k_i} \} \ \text{in} \ L_2(\Omega) ~~~~~~~~~\because H_0^1(\Omega) \subset\subset L_2(\Omega)
$
I've written the proof up to this point. What remains to be proven is the boundedness of $DKf_k$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. If this can be shown, the existence of a convergent subsequence can be proven. I've been struggling with this for two days. Thank you in advance.

Does $\Omega$ have a $C^2$-boundary or something similar?

I don't have condition C.

Ah, sad. I thought about applying some regularity theorems.
